# How many weights does the max-pooling layer have?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, hyper-parameters, filters, pooling, max-pooling

How many weights does the max-pooling layer have?

For example, if there are 10 inputs, a pooling filter of size 2, stride 2, how many weights, including bias, does a max-pooling layer have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A max-pooling layer doesn't have any trainable weights. It has only hyperparameters, but they are non-trainable. The max-pooling process calculates the maximum value of the filter, which consists of no weights and biases. It is purely a way to downscale the data to a smaller dimension.